# New Beta Theme Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.

You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.

If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).

If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it **[in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)** I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Comment: Looks much nicer and I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

It looks too stark/blank for my tastes.  It feels like what Google is trying to do to Gmail...must be the "2010s look" (which was probably influenced by Facebook's absurdly big success), but for me it has zero personality.  Can we at least have a nice logo for the name of the site?

There is also (again, as with Gmail's standard new setting) too much space used; I find it actually *more* readable and legitimate-looking if it uses the same sort of spacing one might see in printed documents.

Comment: (Aside: On your last point, that reminds me of one of the rules-of-thumb for uncluttered business card design: You should be able to place a quarter somewhere on the business card without it touching any of the text.)

Comment: I really miss the quadrille ruled, blue tinted background. Feels bland now.